# Validation Issue in Select : Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

**My Form is like below**

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost:1234/Update" accept-charset="UTF-8">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="bVyYZGPprZKHab8sQXairqhtwszTeQ36LRhp9u2k">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="bVyYZGPprZKHab8sQXairqhtwszTeQ36LRhp9u2k">

    <select class="form-control" name="TypeID">
        <option value="-1">Please select Payment Type</option>
            <option value="2">Bitcoin</option>
            <option value="1">Paypal</option>
            <option value="3">Pioneer</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

**Controller Action Method is like below**

```
public function UpdatePaymentDetails(PaymentDetailsRequest $request) {
}
```

**Request Class is below**

```
class PaymentDetailsRequest extends Request {

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules() {
        return [
            'TypeID' => 'required|min:1',
        ];            
    }
}
```

**What's the problem?**

It is not validating when I don't selected TypeID, Am I missing something?

Comment: Try adding a `numeric` rule to your rules. I have a suspicion that `-1` is being treated as a *string* `"-1"` and thus the `min:1` means the string has to have at least one character.

Comment: I recommend accepting @TomasButeler's. He tweaked on the same thing at the same time, and already has an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `TypeID` is probably being passed as string, and always with a character length of 2 (`-1`), so it's valid according to your own rules. Why don't you just use the conventional empty value as default? This will fail the `required` rule and reject the request.

```
<select class="form-control" name="TypeID">
    <option value="">Please select Payment Type</option>
    <option value="2">Bitcoin</option>
    <option value="1">Paypal</option>
    <option value="3">Pioneer</option>
</select>
```

Alternatively, you can follow @ceejayoz's suggestion and enforce a numeric validation of your `TypeId`, like this:

```
// PaymentDetailsRequest.php

public function rules() {
    return [
        'TypeID' => 'required|numeric|min:1',
    ];            
}
```

Comment: I did the down vote. Because this is a work around and not a solution. See the comment posted by @ceejayoz but if you add the suggestion made by ceejayoz, I will take back downvote and this will be marked accepted.

Comment: @Helper I've incorporated @ceejayoz suggestion. Still, I'm curious as to why you consider tweaking the HTML form a workaround. If the OP is attempting to reject the default value, does it really matter if it's `''` or `-1`, considering it'll never be processed or inserted in the database? I considered `-1` to be unnecessary.

Comment: I considered "`numeric`" a better option and OP is me :) This post was created by me.

Comment: @TomasButeler The `-1` is indeed unnecessary, and I prefer your blank value. However, without the `numeric` rule, Laravel would happily validate `hello` as a valid input, as it has five characters. :-)

Comment: In that case I'd prefer something like `required|in:1,2,3`. I'd use the `in` rule to validate selects and `numeric` for validating inputs of type number.

Comment: @TomasButeler That's fair. :-)